# EO.WebBrowser Инпут данных в HTML строку

Tags: javascript, c#

Всех приветствую.
Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке импортировать свое значение в строку ввода(ниже приложил код). Использовал `GetElementById` и `EvalScript`. Но, по какой-то причине ничего не работает. Страница загружается в окне, но все поля остаются пустыми. Так же, попробовал добавить sleep на 15 секунд, что тоже не помогло. Прошу вашей помощи.

Код:

```
static void Main()
    {
        EO.WebEngine.Engine.Default.Options.UILanguage = "fr";
        Form f = new Form();
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        WebView view = new WebView();
        view.Create(f.Handle);
        view.Url = "https://yandex.ru/";
        Application.Run(f);
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
        view.EvalScript("document.getElementById('text').value='HW'");
    }
```

Comment: А свойство `if(CanEvalScript)` использовать пробовали? Это коммерческий продукт, кстати не кислых бабок стоит (Single Developer License $749), в тех.поддержку писали?

Comment: Уже нашли решение :)

Answer (score 2):

Решили все подобным образом.
Код:

```
static void Main()
{
    EO.WebEngine.Engine.Default.Options.UILanguage = "fr";
    Form f = new Form();
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    WebView view = new WebView();
    view.Create(f.Handle);
    view.LoadUrlAndWait = "https://yandex.ru/";
    view.EvalScript("document.getElementById('text').value='HW'");

    Application.Run(f);
}
```